# Update all values except auto-increment field using PHP / MySql / PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, sql-update

I have a quick question...I am updating all values in a row using a prepared statement and an array.

When initially inserting, my statement looks like this (and works perfect)

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $dbtable VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

The first and last values are `NULL` as the first is an auto increment ID field and last is a timestamp field.

Is there a way to keep my `UPDATE` statement as simple as my `INSERT` statement like this...

```
$sql="UPDATE $dbtable SET (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) WHERE `announcements`.`id` = $id LIMIT 1";
```

I realize this does not work as is due to the first value being an auto increment field, is there a value I could put into my array to 'skip' this field?

This may not be the best way to describe my question but if you need more info, please let me know!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does that even work?  I have never seen that syntax before for an update.  You have to specify the columns AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UPDATE` has no "implicit columns" syntax like `INSERT` does. You have to name all the columns that you want to change.

One alternative you can use in MySQL is `REPLACE`:

```
REPLACE INTO $dbtable VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ...)
```

That way you can pass the current value for your primary key, and change the values of other columns.

Read more about `REPLACE` here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replace.html

Note that this is internally very similar to @Devon's suggestion of using two statements, a `DELETE` followed by an `INSERT`. For example, when you run `REPLACE`, if you have triggers, both the ON DELETE triggers are activated, and then the ON INSERT triggers. It also has side-effects on foreign keys.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I can think of doesn't involve an `UPDATE` at all.

```
DELETE FROM $dbtable WHERE id = $id;
INSERT INTO $dbtable VALUES ($id, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
```

Since you don't want to use the `UPDATE` syntax, this would delete the row and add a new row with the same id, essentially updating it.  I would recommend wrapping it in a transaction so you don't lose your previous row if the insert fails for any reason.